# Client application not registering on SBA server

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-boot-admin

I have an application running as a Spring boot admin server and a couple of client microservices which register successfully on the server - even on Docker.

However, I have one client application which does not register on the SBA server. I have followed the same steps that I did for the other client applications (added dependencies and changed the application.properties file) as is mentioned in the documentation; but this service does not register.

Surprisingly there is nothing in the logs of both the server and the client. I also tried throwing an `UnknownHostException` on purpose by specifying an incorrect `spring.boot.admin.url` and an incorrect `spring.boot.admin.client.url` in the .properties file of the client, but there are still no logs. I've tried restarting docker, restarting intellij, cleared .m2 folder. Nothing seems to help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a problem of the dns-lookup inside the Docker-Container, try to start a bash  ....`docker container exec -it <yourcontainer> bash`... and check if a nslookup at the SBA fqdn works

In SBA 2.0.1 the property has changed ... it is spring.boot.admin.**client**.url 
NOT spring.boot.admin.url